# Sort a JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, sorting

I am trying ot sort a **JSON** Object using **Python**.

I have the following object :

```
{ 
  "text": "hello world",
  "predictions": 
   [
     {"class": "Class 1", "percentage": 4.63},
     {"class": "Class 2", "percentage": 74.68},
     {"class": "Class 3", "percentage": 9.38},
     {"class": "Class 4", "percentage": 5.78},
     {"class": "Class 5", "percentage": 5.53}
   ]
}
```

And I want to have this object instead :

```
{ 
  "text": "hello world",
  "predictions": 
   [
     {"class": "Class 2", "percentage": 74.68},
     {"class": "Class 3", "percentage": 9.38},
     {"class": "Class 4", "percentage": 5.78},
     {"class": "Class 5", "percentage": 5.53},
     {"class": "Class 1", "percentage": 4.63}
   ]
}
```

In fact, I want to order my array of objects by percentage.

I have tried this command :

```
sorted_obj = sorted(json_obj['predictions'], key=lambda k: k['percentage'], reverse=True)
```

And I had this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Any help is needed,

Thanks

Comment: JSON arrays are parsed to Python `list`s and JSON objects to Python `dict`s. `dict`s are unordered in Python. You would need some ordered container. Try to store the data in an `OrderedDict`:  `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: I trust you realise "nothing worked" is an unhelpful description of your problem. It implies it's the reader's duty to determine the exact nature of the problem. Most people will walk away, others like me will add a comment intended to be helpful, but very few will attempt to answer such an ill-defined question. Give yourself a chance to get help, tell us what's wrong!

Comment: @Adirio - he isn't trying to order a dict, he's trying to order a list of dicts based on one of the values in the dicts.

Comment: @holdenweb true, my bad

Comment: What does `sorted_obj` become?

Comment: I edited the post :)

Comment: @Adirio yeah, made similar mistakes myself a million times, no sweat.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `sorted` to sort the values, something like this :

```
json_obj = { 
  "text": "hello world",
  "predictions": 
   [
     {"class": "Class 1", "percentage": 4.63},
     {"class": "Class 2", "percentage": 74.68},
     {"class": "Class 3", "percentage": 9.38},
     {"class": "Class 4", "percentage": 5.78},
     {"class": "Class 5", "percentage": 5.53}
   ]
}

sorted_obj = dict(json_obj) 
sorted_obj['predictions'] = sorted(json_obj['predictions'], key=lambda x : x['percentage'], reverse=True)

print(sorted_obj)
print(json_obj)
```

This will result in :

```
# The sorted values based on 'predictions' -> 'percentage'
{'predictions': [{'percentage': 74.68, 'class': 'Class 2'}, {'percentage': 9.38, 'class': 'Class 3'}, {'percentage': 5.78, 'class': 'Class 4'}, {'percentage': 5.53, 'class': 'Class 5'}, {'percentage': 4.63, 'class': 'Class 1'}], 'text': 'hello world'}

# The original json_obj will remain unchanged as we have created a new object sorted_obj from values of json_obj using dict()
{'text': 'hello world', 'predictions': [{'class': 'Class 1', 'percentage': 4.63}, {'class': 'Class 2', 'percentage': 74.68}, {'class': 'Class 3', 'percentage': 9.38}, {'class': 'Class 4', 'percentage': 5.78}, {'class': 'Class 5', 'percentage': 5.53}]}
```

Comment: Note that this is an in-place edit of the original json. It will overwrite it.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil No, it wont. I am creating new object using the old values and not creating a direct reference.

Comment: My bad, I thought replacing `list` in a key should change the original as well.

Comment: Why have you done this? `sorted_obj = dict(json_obj) `, whats its significance?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost right, you probably want to create a copy of the dictionary and then replace `predictions`'s value to the sorted object. I'm assuming that you want to leave the original `json_obj` unchanged, hence the `deepcopy` (although it is unnecessary if we are simply doing a reassignment instead of in-place `.sort`).

```
>>> json_obj = { 
...   "text": "hello world",
...   "predictions": 
...    [
...      {"class": "Class 1", "percentage": 4.63},
...      {"class": "Class 2", "percentage": 74.68},
...      {"class": "Class 3", "percentage": 9.38},
...      {"class": "Class 4", "percentage": 5.78},
...      {"class": "Class 5", "percentage": 5.53}
...    ]
... }
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> sorted_json_obj = deepcopy(json_obj)
>>> sorted_json_obj['predictions'] = sorted(json_obj['predictions'], key=lambda k: k['percentage'], reverse=True)
>>> sorted_json_obj
{'predictions': [{'class': 'Class 2', 'percentage': 74.68},
                 {'class': 'Class 3', 'percentage': 9.38},
                 {'class': 'Class 4', 'percentage': 5.78},
                 {'class': 'Class 5', 'percentage': 5.53},
                 {'class': 'Class 1', 'percentage': 4.63}],
 'text': 'hello world'}
```

Comment: My bad, my object wasn't well parsed. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @ben @Ashish Note :  For simple data structures, using `deepcopy` can be an overkill, since it does so much accounting, reference tracking, and the like. Look at this : https://writeonly.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/deepcopy-is-a-pig-for-simple-data/

Comment: Yep, reassignment would be okay here, but in-place sorting won't be. Had a [great discussion in chat about it](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36506364#36506364). Thanks @SatishGarg!