# Sorting a JSON Object

Tags: python, arrays, json, sorting

I'm new to JSON and Python, and I'm attempting to load a json file that I created from disk to manipulate and output to an xml file.  I've gotten most of it figured out, except, I want to 'sort' the JSON file after I load it by a certain value.

Example of json file:

```
{
   "0" : {
     "name": "John Doe",
     "finished": "4",
     "logo": "http://someurl.com/icon.png"
   },
   "1" : {
     "name": "Jane Doe",
     "finished": "10",
     "logo": "http://anotherurl.com/icon.png"
   },
   "2" : {
     "name": "Jacob Smith",
     "finished": "3",
     "logo": "http://example.com/icon.png"
   }
}
```

What I want to do is sort 'tree' by the 'finished' key.

```
JSONFILE = "file.json"

with open(CHANS) as json_file:
    tree = json.load(json_file)
```

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255909/sort-a-json-using-python

Comment: but you cannot sort it, since it's a dictionary of dictionaries, not a list of dictionaries. Unless you want to use `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: Better to keep it sorted in the file the whole time, and use `object_pairs_hook` to preserve the *existing* order at load time.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how do you "consume" the `tree` dictionary. are you using `tree.keys()`, `tree.values()` or `tree.items()`?

### `tree.keys()`

```py
ordered_keys = sorted(tree.keys(), key=lambda k: int(tree[k]['finished']))
```

### `tree.values()`

```py
ordered_keys = sorted(tree.values(), key=lambda v: int(v['finished']))
```

### `tree.items()`

```py
ordered_keys = sorted(tree.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[1]['finished']))
```

You only keep in mind that JSON is what's inside the actual file, the result of `json.load()` is just a Python value/object, so just work with them.

If you are walking over the sorted dictionary once, the above snippets will work just fine. However if you need to access it multiple times, then I would follow ~Jean-François suggestion and use `OrderedDict`, with something like:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
tree = OrderedDict(sorted(tree.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[1]['finished'])))
```

That way the sorting operation (arguably the most expensive) is done just once.